# Ruby-Capybara Page load Wait [ To set up a method in Ruby-Capybara-Selenium-Cucumber embeded framework for a web Automation]

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, page-load-time

I have to calculate the **Webpage-Rendering time** on each navigation with in the Automation framework created with embeded[**Ruby-capybara-selenium-cucumber**].
some Webpages are Ajax developed.

```
#Xpath
SIGNIN_BTN = "//div/button[contains(.,'Sign In')]"    
VERIFY_BTN = "//div/button[contains(.,'NEXTBUTTON')]"

t1 = Time.now    
      visit "http://google.com"    
t2 = Time.now   
pageloadtime1 = t2-t1  
puts pageloadtime1 

t3 = Time.now  
find(:xpath, SIGNIN_BTN).click  
t4 = Time.now  
pageloadtime2 = t4-t3
puts pageloadtime2 

t5 = Time.now   
find(:xpath, VERIFY_BTN ).click  
t6 = Time.now  
pageloadtime3 = t6-t5
puts pageloadtime3
```

But as per logic, it doesn't give a complete page-rendering time,
instead at a click instantly the time is given as output before the
 **page-rendering/DOM** is completed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This works for me.**

*calculating with Ruby and Jscript - document.readyState, Create a generic method and call it.*

```
SIGNIN_BTN = "//div/button[contains(.,'Sign In')]" 
NEXT_BTN = "//div/button[contains(.,'NEXTBUTTON')]"

visit "https://gmail.com/"  
timewait = pagetime_time  
puts "LAUNCH GMAIL | PAGELOAD TIME :#{timewait}"  

find(:xpath, SIGNIN_BTN).click  
timewait = pagetime_time  
puts "SIGN IN GMAIL | PAGELOAD TIME :#{timewait}"  

find(:xpath, NEXT_BTN ).click  
timewait = pagetime_time  
puts "NEXT GMAIL | PAGELOAD TIME :#{timewait}"  

def pagetime_time  
  time1 = Time.now  
  timeloop = 0  
  while timeloop < 500  
    if (Capybara.current_session.driver.execute_script('var browserState = document.readyState; return browserState;') == 'complete')  
      time2 = Time.now  
      break  
    end  
    timeloop + 1  
  end  
  timeWait = (time2 - time1) * 1000  
  return timeWait  
end
```

Comment: IF it works for you - great, as long as you realize you're depending on completely non-guaranteed behavior that could change in any minor release of any of the relevant gems,  and also on driver specific methods for no apparent reason.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole May I know why it's completely non-guaranteed behavior? it works fine always, the only problem I can see here,If program moves to next line immediately after the click where you are checking this Javascript, it will tell you page load complete but after a few milliseconds page starts to load so it might end up wrong but the way to overcome is to wait until element goes stale and then check whether page loads completely using the above Javascript he has written in his comment ..continued in next comment....

Comment: @ThomasWalpole If you use Legacy Firefox driver this page load completely not a problem, If you use geckodriver, then also page load is not a problem because they seemed to have fixed in the last version but I see still it's not reliable because it releases the control even before it loads completely. It's something we can't check it from the program, so we have to depend on JS, no other way. This is the only place we have to completely depends upon driver. Rest of the other things like wait until finding an element we can manage it from local language binding like WATIR does.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Thanks a lot. after reading you comments I've got a clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When using Capybara there is no guarantee that a page has fully loaded (whatever that means) when visit returns, and there is no guarantee any actions triggered by clicking an element have completed (or even started) when it returns. This is because Capybara knows nothing about the status of the page other than what the "browser" tells it is visible on the page. Using just Capybara the best you can do for timings is the time between you telling the browser to do something, and the time an element, expected to be on the page when "loaded", appears on the page. In your instance that would mean something like this

```
SIGNIN_BTN = ".//div/button[contains(.,'Sign In')]"    
VERIFY_BTN = ".//div/button[contains(.,'NEXTBUTTON')]"

t1 = Time.now    
visit "http://google.com"    
signin_btn = find(:xpath, SIGNIN_BTN) # wait until signin button is visible on page
t2 = Time.now   
pageloadtime1 = t2-t1  
puts pageloadtime1 

t3 = Time.now  
signin_btn.click 
verify_btn = find(:xpath, VERIFY_BTN ) # wait until the verify button is visible on page
t4 = Time.now  
pageloadtime2 = t4-t3
puts pageloadtime2 

t5 = Time.now   
verify_btn.click
something = find(:xpath, './/xpath of something visible on page when action has completed')  
t6 = Time.now  
pageloadtime3 = t6-t5
puts pageloadtime3
```

Note, these measurements will all include some overhead since the waiting behavior while attempting to find the elements has overhead and 50ms delay between each attempt.  Also note the SIGNIN_BTN and VERIFY_BTN xpaths now start with `.//` - You should get used to starting all xpaths used with Capybara with `.//` rather than `//` unless you really need `//` and understand the difference (it breaks scoping on the page) - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap

Comment: Thank You, but Jscript - document.readystate with ruby works fine form me